# How to best position Apache Kafka to be a message broker for many isolated clients

Tags: apache-kafka, architecture, publish-subscribe

My organization has an AWS hosted Spring Boot application with Apache Kafka currently facilitating message exchange for ~50 topics ("the cloud application"). Within client facilities (physical locations) we have a processing machine which handles logic and commands from the cloud. All clients have their own local machines. The desire is to allow the client/cloud to make use of the same Kafka topics but disallow one client form receiving the others.

Many Kafka instances does not scale. What is the appropriate way to enable Kafka to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Isolated clients can still use one cluster. You can use ACLs to control access

Answer (score 1):

> Many Kafka instances does not scale

Depends how you manage it. You can use Ansible/Puppet/Chef and Terraform to quickly setup Kafka clusters in any environment.

You can use MirrorMaker or Kafka Connect to pull topics from a cloud datacenter into a <strike>"physical"</strike> private one.

But, the end result is that you have *some consumer* pulling data from a remote cluster and processing it.

> disallow one client from receiving the others

"Other" what? Other datacenters? That would be a network rule, not a Kafka problemm, IMO.

Other Kafka topics? You can setup SASL + JAAS for having a basic auth layer.

More information - [Kafka Security 101](https://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-security-authorization-authentication-encryption/) (old post, information may be somewhat outdated)

[Docs on Kafka Security](https://docs.confluent.io/current/security/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see an ideal solution here, but if your load requires Kafka and you need Client isolation by authorization than the way to go would be to create a destination Topic per client and enforce ACLs on Topic READ / WRITE as mentioned [in the post above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539223/6284449).

The possible drawback of this approach could be a hit to performance or possibly needing to extend a big enough cluster to support the load and keep the SLAs as needed.

### Planning and calculating estimations

As presented in the [blog post about partition number optimization](https://www.confluent.io/blog/how-choose-number-topics-partitions-kafka-cluster/), the general rule of thumb to keep your Kafka cluster safe, and our first step is:

```
NumPartitionsPerBroker = 100 x NumOfBrokers x ReplicationFactor
```

Where:

- NumPartitionsPerBroker = Maximum load of partitions on a single Kafka broker in the cluster.
- NumOfBrokers = Number of Kafka brokers in the current cluster setting.
- ReplicationFactor = Default / Average replication factor, essentially how many peer brokers can share the load of partition leadership.

The next step would be to figure out how many Partitions you are possibly epecting in the next months / years:

```
TotalExpectedPartitions = 
    (NumTopics x AvgNumParts) x 
    [(1 + % GrowthTopics) x (1 + % GrowthParts)] ^ TimeInterval
```

Where:

- NumTopics = Number of topics
- AvgNumParts = Average number of partitions per topic (producers / consumers per topic)
- GrowthTopics = Expected growth in topics
- GrowthPrts = Expected growth in partitions
- TimeInterval = Estimation of how many Months / Years / etc are you planning ahead

And finally the two numbers should add up in the following way:

```
NumPartitionsPerBroker x NumOfBrokers = TotalExpectedPartitions
```

Hope this helps :)